# Is there a way to track calls throttled by API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been using CloudWatch to track metrics against API Gateway and Lambda, and it shows throttled calls for Lambda, but is there any way to see the number of calls that are throttled earlier by API Gateway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet, but we are planning on addressing this in the near future. Can't provide an ETA. But it would be similar to Lambda in that there will be a metric counter for throttled requests.

Comment: @jack-kohn-aws your answer is from 2016, has this been addressed already?

Comment: @jackko its been 4 years, has this been addressed already?

Comment: Sniff, yeah it seems important to have such metric, but it's not there yet: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html

Comment: Just writing this in 2023 to conclude that "near future" > 6½ years. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

You could setup `CloudWatch` alerts with `SNS` notifications to receive info about throttled request. Another way could be tracking the throttled `HTTP 429` status on the client.