# Is it possible to set up API Gateway throttling alarm with cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have api gateway set up with cdk code. I set up different alarms for ServerError and Latency. I also would like to set up a throttling alarm. I see how to set up [throttling itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.ThrottleSettings.html) but I couldn't find how to set up alarm. All other alarms I set using [aws-cloudwatch lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html) but api gateway doesn't have `metricThrottles()`. What's a proper way to create throttling alarms with cdk for api gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a DIY job.  API Gateway [sends `4XX` error metrics to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-metrics-and-dimensions.html), but not `429` errors alone.  To isolate throttles using the CDK, you would:

1. [capture the API logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.StageOptions.html) in CloudWatch
2. create a [MetricFilter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_logs.MetricFilter.html) to isolate the `429` events
3. set an [Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Alarm.html) on that custom metric

For context beyond the CDK, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414893/1103511) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966288/is-there-a-way-to-track-calls-throttled-by-api-gateway) SO question.